# Time picker Cancel and Ok button use different colors

Tags: flutter, themes

I currently using Flutter's Time picker and managed to change the 'Cancel' and 'Ok' button to be my current theme colors. However, I would like for the 'Cancel' button to be in a different color and keep the 'Ok' button red, to emphasize the other button. Is there a way without extracting the time picker into my own implementation. (I seen that suggested in some other stackoverflow answer)

[image]

Comment: did i answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're really sure about wanting **2 different colors** for **each button** the solution is indeed a bit complicated :

- *You could just modify the `time_picker.dart` file but **it's really not best practice** - also you would lose all your changes after upgrading your Flutter SDK*

So the only way to real way to do it is to clone Flutter Package - import it into your project & manually edit the `time_picker.dart` file :

*around line 2128* edit this :

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: _handleCancel,
              child: Text(widget.cancelText ?? localizations.cancelButtonLabel),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: _handleOk,
              child: Text(widget.confirmText ?? localizations.okButtonLabel),
```

to this :

```
TextButton(
              onPressed: _handleCancel,
              child: Text(widget.cancelText ?? localizations.cancelButtonLabel, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: _handleOk,
              child: Text(widget.confirmText ?? localizations.okButtonLabel, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
            ),
```

- then just import this new package where you'd like to use it

---

###### Second solution - if you don't care having the same color on each button

You can update your `MaterialApp(theme: )` & change the `textButtonTheme` `foregroundColor`

like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
      const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
        MaterialState.pressed,
        MaterialState.hovered,
        MaterialState.focused,
      };
      if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
        return Colors.blue;
      }
      return Colors.red;
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Time Picker Themed Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor)),
        ),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Updated Time Picker]

But for a nicer look like this :

[image: Material App TimePicker Theme]

checkout https://material.io/components/time-pickers/flutter#theming-time-pickers